# bounded subset in $\ell_1(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a subset composed of countable elements in $\ell_1(\mathbb{N})$. Suppose that $X$ is bounded in $\ell_s(\mathbb{N})$ for all $1<s\leq2$, that is for any $1<s\leq 2$, there exists a postive constant $M_s$ which may depend on $s$ such that $\|x\|_s\leq M_s$ for all $x\in X$. Now the question is whether $X$ is bounded in $\ell_1(\mathbb{N})$ or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $x^n_k=\begin{cases}\frac1k&\text{if }1\le k\le n\\ 0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ and $X=\{x^n\,:\, n\in\Bbb N\}$. $X$ is bounded in $\ell^s$ for all $s>1$, but not for $s=1$.